# python global variable is not saved global

Tags: python, global-variables

```
NexusConnectedClients = []

class Thread1(NexusCore.Thread):
    def Run():
        global NexusConnectedClients
        if(IncomingCommand == "ADDCLIENT"):
            NewClientOBJ = [
                LastCID,
                ClientType,
                ClientADDR,
                ClientObject,
                Args[1],
                Args[2],
                '{"events":[]}'
            ]
            NexusConnectedClients.append(NewClientOBJ)
        elif(IncomingCommand == "LISTCLIENTS"):
            SendResponse(NexusConnectedClients)
```

When i add an client, it is ok. When i read the `NexusConnectedClients` variable, it is add to the list.
But when i run the LISTCLIENTS function, the list is empty. What is wrong?

I Simplified the code a bit. all the variables are set and all other global variables work as they should.

**EDIT**
I found the mistake, nothing wrong with this code but another function deleted the element from the `NexusConnectedClients` array

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please answer it and accept your own answer so it can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Didn't remove an line of code from previous testing. That line resetted the array

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare `NexusConnectedClients` as global since it is visible in the `run` method. A variable must be declared global when you want to (re)bind a name in the global scope. When a variable is modifiable, and lists are, just modify it.

Instead what you have to do is to regulate the access to the `NexusConnectedClients`. You are modifying a shared variable inside a thread, maybe more than one. Use a lock. Said that, I think nothing more could be said in a such small snippet.

Comment: tried it, didn't solve the problem. It's very strange. Sometimes it does save the element. Sometimes not. Very strange. but 1 of the client applications works always as it should, others don't.

Comment: @alpjef: the code is too short to trying to investigate the problem. Where are the variables,`IncomingCommand`, `Args`, etc., coming from? Are they managed by some thread? For what I can see, the `SendResponse` could do something like this: `NexusConnectedClients[:] = []`. Take a look at http://sscce.org/ and most important, it should be self contained.